# vb6 ActiveReports1 : How to build a report that has 3 subreports with different datasources

Tags: vb6, recordset, activereports

I have an old old app that utilizes ActiveReports1. i pass a variable to the report itself and then i make three query calls to SQL each dumping into its own recordset. Each query has a specific where clause, since vb6 doesnt have linq, im biting the bullet and calling sql 3 times. :( .Anyways, i have three sections, electrical, physical, and confined space. how can i make 3 subreports inside this report? i attached an example of the report sections. Example of data, So my confined space query are ALL records tied to an id. electrical is basically all records with that ID that DO have a string value in a column called "X", Physical are all the records that DO NOT have a string value in that same column. and confined is just all records regardless of that column value. Not a vb6 programmer so any direction would be great. Normally i would break a datatable on a column and it will group that way..in .NET but not sure where to begin on this one.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure quite what the question is? Seems like you are asking about a lot of different things. Can you narrow it down and focus?

Comment: If each of these is truly stand-alone (three separate SQL statements), what is preventing you from just adding three subreports to the designer?

Comment: @tcarvin, That is exactly what the solution was. i made 3 subreports  and added them to the designer.  but i did it in active reports 11. doing this in active reports 1 was  not really  that simple and that was the basis for this post's question.

Comment: @Edgar does that mean you have solved this issue now?  Or are you still not able to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding different data source for each sub report, you can do this for any number of sub reports by following these **general** steps:

1. Create your sub report in a separate file (subreport1.rpx)
2. Create a SubReport object on your parent report (srpt1)
3. In the Script of your parent report instantiate a Report and DataSource
4. In Script, load your sub rpx, provide a connection string, & SQL statement

Here is an example script:

```
Private rptSub As GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport
Private ds As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Data.SqlDBDataSource()

Sub GroupFooter1_Format
    rptSub = New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport()
    rptSub.LoadLayout("MyCustomFolder\subreport1.rpx")
    ds.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"
    ds.SQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ImportantField = 'FilterValue'"
    rptSub.DataSource = ds
    me.srpt1.Report = rptSub
End Sub
```

Here's a working example (not exactly same as above generalized code) that works with a version of ActiveReports that's embedded into a WinForm application.

[image: Working Example]